# Is there a way to distinguish between objects of different interface types in Javascript/TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a library which defines the following interfaces:

```
LocalUser {
  data {
    value: LocalDataValue
  },
  ...various other methods etc...
}
RemoteUser {
  data {
    value: RemoteDataValue
  },
  ...various other methods etc...
}
```

Then it gives me a User which is defined like this (I can work out which type of user it is based on how it was obtained, but there doesn't seem to be a way to actually pass that information on):

```
User {
  value: LocalUser|RemoteUser
}
```

because for the vast majority of my code it doesn't matter.  However, at one point I need to know whether I'm dealing with a `LocalUser`, because I only want to do a particular operation on `LocalUsers`.  Is there a way to know whether a `LocalUser` is a `RemoteUser` or a `LocalUser`?

I can't find anywhere in the documentation which tells me what the difference is between them, though I know that some methods only appear on `LocalUser` and not on `RemoteUser` (eg I can do `localUser.enable()` but `remoteUser.enable()` doesn't work).

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
if(myUnknownUser isInstanceOf (LocalUser)) { doSomething() }
```

or a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases you should use [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Consider this example:

```js
type LocalUser = {
  tag: 'LocalUser';
  name: 'John'
}

type RemoteUser = {
  tag: 'RemoteUser';
  name: 'David'
}
type User = LocalUser | RemoteUser

// typeguard
const isLocal = (user: User): user is LocalUser => user.tag === 'LocalUser'

// typeguard
const isRemote = (user: User): user is RemoteUser => user.tag === 'RemoteUser'

declare var user: User;

if (isLocal(user)) {
  const x = user // LocalUser
}

if (isRemote(user)) {
  const x = user // RemoteUser
}
```

It is up to you how you will implement typeguard

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't heard of typeguards, but I'll go and do some research now.  Thanks!